# Error in configuring and operating FABRIC Raft

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I tried to start the network with RAFT following the BYFN example but I'm stuck in a problem related to signcert certificate that miss from the `crypto-config` folder after the cryptogen tool has been executed.

I follow the following steps:

First, re-generate the crypto material (file crypto-config.YAML already has specs about the orderers), then I start the container (doesn't matter if I do it manually or executing byfn.sh, the error is always the same). The logs tell me that orderer containers doesn't find signcert certificates and exited. Actually when I get in the `crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp` folder, I just see `admincerts/` and `keystore/` folder. I tried re-executing the cryptogen tool but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: can you please add the output of the terminal to your question? upload it to some site.

Comment: Hi yacovm, I solved the problem by erasing and re-creating from 0 the criptomaterial  and the cripto-config.YAML. Thanks.